# P2P, RPC and Server related code

Tags: rpc, source, p2p, source-code-documentation

Is there a recommended source of information as to how Monero interacts with wallets and other nodes?
I'd like to get as much information as possible about the structure of the source code and am having some trouble understanding just from looking at the source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daemons (nodes) talk to each other using the epee levin protocol.

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/tree/master/contrib/epee/include/net

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/p2p/net_node.h

Both the wallet and daemon also expose JSON-RPC servers (so JSON sent over HTTP).

The methods are documented at:
https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html

and
https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html

With source code scattered in various places. The underlying server code is in:
https://github.com/monero-project/monero/tree/master/contrib/epee/include/net

With protocols defined in:
https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/rpc/core_rpc_server_commands_defs.h

and
https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server_commands_defs.h